# JDK 17 Java Security is deprecated

Tags: java, groovy, java-17, java-security-manager

We are using Java security classes in our project and in JDK 17 these are marked for removal. What is the alternative for these classes.
We are using the following classes and methods in our project for Script policy security.

```
 Security.setProperty(), 
  Policy.setPolicy(new ScriptPolicy(getClass().getClassLoader()));, 
  System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
```

Policies like

```
 _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("java.version", "read"));
  _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("java.vm.name", "read"));
 _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("groovy.*", "read"));
```

As per JDK 17 migration "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-7DACC239-E71D-4B89-B582-201EA7CEBC38"

There is no alternative yet.

```
    public class ScriptPolicy extends Policy

and 
  
  
From this method, we are getting permissions.

   

     protected void _addStaticPermissions()
            {
                
                    _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("java.version", "read"));
                    _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("java.vm.name", "read"));
                    _groovyPermissions.add(new PropertyPermission("groovy.*", "read"));
        }
    
    

This is the code where we assign the permissions to Policy.

 if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            String restricted = Security.getProperty("package.access");
            Security.setProperty("package.access",
                    restricted + "com.xyz");
            Policy.setPolicy(new ScriptPolicy(getClass().getClassLoader()));
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? You didn't make any.

Comment: I wanted to know is there any alternatives to achieve the same functionality without using java security package

Comment: No, read the https://openjdk.org/jeps/411 document from the link you shared.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on where `ScriptPolicy` and your `_groovyPermissions` come from.

Comment: I’m sure “for Script policy security” has meaning to you, but it doesn’t mean much to us.  Edit your question and explain what you’re really using security permissions for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question with some more code.

Comment: Your update doesn't say what `_groovyPermission` is or where it comes from, or what you are actually using security permissions for.  Clearly, you can't use a security manager ... but we can't suggest viable alternatives unless you explain what you are currently using it for.  What does "Script policy security" actually mean?

Comment: *"There is no alternative yet."*  - There will probably **never** be a replacement for SecurityManager.  Don't hold your breath waiting for one.  The idea that you can safely run *untrusted* Java (or Groovy) code in a JVM sandbox must be abandoned.

Comment: private final List<Permission> _groovyPermissions = new ArrayList<>();

We are adding permissions to it. When the Groovy script runs in JVM we do not want to user to set values to environment variables through Groovy script for example AWS_SESSION_TOKEN etc.

Comment: Regarding alternative approaches, JEP411 (which your link links to) states _"Security is better achieved by providing integrity at lower levels of the Java Platform — by, for example, strengthening module boundaries (JEP 403) to prevent access to JDK implementation details, and hardening the implementation itself — and by isolating the entire Java runtime from sensitive resources via out-of-process mechanisms such as containers and hypervisors."_ Consider modifying your question to clarify specific concerns over Security Manager's removal. What would be lost?

Answer (score -1):

Here some Java security classes, including policy, security, and SecurityManager, have been chosen for removal in JDK 17. The JDK does not presently offer a direct substitute for these classes. You can fix this by investigating third-party security libraries, which provide a variety of security features, such as Apache Shiro, Spring Security, or OWASP Java Encoder. These libraries might offer different ways to implement property rights, script policy security, and other security management features in your project.

I hope this can help you to get some solution in your project.